# Why convert map function to list in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter

For a school assignment, I am analyzing tweets. From the gained Twitter data, we are only interested in the text of the tweet. They are putting it in a DataFrame with this code:

```
tweets['text'] =    list(map(lambda tweet: tweet['text'], tweets_data))
```

I do not understand why the map function is converted to a list. The DataFrame looks good like desired, but I can't understand why it needs to be converted to a list. Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you want to assign it as a column, map returns a map object which is a generator I believe. Let's a have a look with a simplified example:

Suppose we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": list("abc")})
print(df)

  col1
0    a
1    b
2    c
```

And we have a function which is a generator and it simply yields each value of the list:

```
def get_column(values: list):
    for i in values:
        yield i
```

As you can see, if we assign it directly as a column, it will return the generator object:

```
df["col2"] = get_column([1, 2, 3])
print(df)

  col1                                             col2
0    a  <generator object get_column at 0x7fbb1e2ca9e0>
1    b  <generator object get_column at 0x7fbb1e2ca9e0>
2    c  <generator object get_column at 0x7fbb1e2ca9e0>
```

But converting it to a list will give us the correct result.

```
df["col2"] = list(get_column([1, 2, 3]))
print(df)

  col1  col2
0    a     1
1    b     2
2    c     3
```